# Reference request on determining whether or not a group of finite order is simple or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I want to know the best (most efficient and simple is what I'd classify as best) techniques to tell whether or not a group of finite order is simple. These are standard exercises but I don't know of any book that, say, gives me many different ways to classify the groups of finite order up to $1000$ or something, for example, and this or material similar to it would be really helpful to me.

Comment: I have some final year undergraduate lecture notes on group theory that finish with a classification of simple groups of order up to 500. They are not (as far as I know) publicly available online, but if you e-mail me I can send you a copy. Some of the orders up to 1000 are challenging. The most difficult one is proving that there is no simple group of order 720. See the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41958)

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but: Do you know that they are all classified? So one technique would be to check if your given group is in the list.

Comment: @user1729 Yes, I'm aware, but I'm gonna have to prove that a few of them are not simple on exams, so that list on its own does nothing for me...

Comment: Just checking :-) Also, if you want to prove "not simple" then look at the order. Every group of [odd-order is soluble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit–Thompson_theorem), as is every group of order $p^aq^b$ (with $p$, $q$ prime). As non-abelian simple groups are easily seen to be non-soluble, these results are applicable to you. That said, these two results are non-trivial (especially the odd-order theorem).

Comment: Section 6.2 of Dummit and Foote gives some techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia provides a [list of finite simple groups of small order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups#Non-cyclic_simple_groups_of_small_order). As you will see, there are only 5 non-cyclic simple groups of order < 1000. You can also use [GAP small groups library](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/SmallGrp-1.3/doc/chap1.html#X7C16EA1580AC7586).

**EDIT**. You can also look at [Orders of non abelian simple groups](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/simplegroups.html).